# How can I commit my changes if I am working with a read only svn, in order to work with it on different computers?

Tags: svn, commit

I use SVN and I am working on a project which is read only. I would like to make my own modification of this code, but also get the official updates.

I am used to use svn for my projects and commit my changes so I can share the files on different computers and work on those different computers on the same project.

However if the repository is not mine, and is read only, I can not commit anything. How could I make my own repository from the read only one, and also get the official updates, and be able to commit my source change?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What have you tried, if anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pure Subversion, you can't. The repository itself is read-only and you simply can't save your changes to it. There's only one repo, and that's it.

It might be possible to duplicate the entire repository to your local system using [rsvndump](http://rsvndump.sourceforge.net/). You duplicate the repository, set it up on your own server where you can give yourself read and **write** permissions. You can then use `svn switch` to switch the location of your working copy to your repository. Unfortunately, you also lose the ease of getting the remote repository changes by simply doing a `svn update`. To get the remote repo changes, you have to remote dump, filter, and load to your repository again.

You can also try [git-svn](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html). Git-svn will checkout from a Subversion repository and create a local Git repository on your system. Then, you can commit changes to your local Git repository and have a version control system you can use for this project. Git-svn will also let you keep merging changes from the remote Subversion repository back to your local Git repository.

Comment: Thanks you a lot, that was helpul!